# Replace character from specific position using sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replace

I am using SQL Server 2008 .I want to replace "<" character from string but i dont want to replace `"<"` from `"<br>"`. So i want to basically remove `"<"` at specific position. My string has following values.

```
declare @MyString as varchar(max)
SET @MyString = '!"#$%''()*+,-/:;=?@[\]^_`{|}~&><)<br/>'
```

Can anyone guide me to how do the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace("<b", "@@@"), then Replace("<", "") and then again Replace("@@@", "<b").... Instead of "@@@" put something that for sure not in your string...

Comment: Your sample string doesn't contain `'<br>'`.  Is there some rule you are following?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@MyString ,'<br/>','mybr'),'<','Your value to replace'),'mybr','<br/>')
```